# AbpEntityChanges is not recorded for module

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I turned on the EntityHistory in the module, but when I edit a data, AbpEntityChanges is not recorded.Now my dbContext looks like this,If I use AbpZeroDbContext, I must have TTenant, TRole, TUser?  I don't need any of that, so I'm using the EntityChangeEnthelper of AbpDbContext, which still doesn't work:

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkModule), typeof(ReportDesignCoreModule))]
public class ReportDesignDataModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabled = true;
        Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabledForAnonymousUsers = true;

        Configuration.DefaultNameOrConnectionString = ConnectionStringConstruction.ConnectionString;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        Database.SetInitializer<ReportDesignDbContext>(null);
    }
}
```

The entity code:

```
[Audited]
public class PDEDataSource : BaseEntity<int>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 名称
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 简介
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 类型: sqlserver、webapi
    /// </summary>
    public int Type { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 连接字符串
    /// </summary>
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

The base entity code:

```
public class BaseEntity<T> : Entity<T>, IHasCreationTime, IHasModificationTime
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 创建人Id
    /// </summary>
    public int? CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 创建人姓名或账号
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string CreatorUser { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 创建时间
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 修改人Id
    /// </summary>
    public int? LastModifierUserId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 修改人名字或账号
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string LastModifierUser { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 最后编辑时间
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? LastModificationTime { get; set; }
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        this.CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

The DbContext code:

```
    public class ReportDesignDbContext : AbpDbContext //AbpZeroCommonDbContext
{
    #region 审计日志
    public virtual IDbSet<AuditLog> AuditLog { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region 实体更改EntityChangeSets
    public virtual IDbSet<EntityChange> EntityChanges { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<EntityChangeSet> EntityChangeSets { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<EntityPropertyChange> EntityPropertyChanges { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region
    public virtual IDbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<PDEDataSource> PDEDataSource { set; get; }
    #endregion

    public ReportDesignDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            var changedEntities = ApplyAbpConcepts();
            var result = base.SaveChanges();
            EntityChangeEventHelper.TriggerEvents(changedEntities);
            return result;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            LogDbEntityValidationException(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var changeReport = ApplyAbpConcepts();
            var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            await EntityChangeEventHelper.TriggerEventsAsync(changeReport);
            return result;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            LogDbEntityValidationException(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PDEDataSource>().Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(50);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PDEDataSource>().Property(t => t.Description).HasMaxLength(200);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PDEDataSource>().Property(t => t.ConnectionString).HasMaxLength(200);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The controller code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/datasoucre")]
public class DataSourceController : ReportDesignControllerBase
{
    private readonly IDataSourceService _dataSource;
    public DataSourceController(IDataSourceService dataSource)
    {
        _dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 数据源列表（带分页）
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">分页参数等</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet, Route()]
    public PagedResultDto<GetDataSourceListOutputDto> GetDataSourceList([FromUri] GetDataSourceListInputDto input)
    {
        var result = _dataSource.GetDataSourceList(input);
        return result;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 新增数据源
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">数据源信息</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost, Route()]
    public async Task AddDataSourceAsync([FromBody] AddDataSourceInputDto input)
    {
        await _dataSource.AddDataSourceAsync(input);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 获取数据源详情
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">数据源Id，必传</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet, Route("detail/{id}")]
    public async Task<GetDataSourceDetailOutputDto> GetDataSourceDetailAsync(int id)
    {
        var result = await _dataSource.GetDataSourceDetailAsync(id);
        return result;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 删除数据源
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">数据源id，必传</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpDelete, Route("{id}")]
    public async Task DeleteDataSourceAsync(int id)
    {
        await _dataSource.DeleteDataSourceAsync(id);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 编辑数据源
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">数据源id，必传</param>
    /// <param name="input">新的数据源信息</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPut, Route("{id}")]
    public async Task UpdateDataSourceAsync(int id, [FromBody] UpdateDataSourceInputDto input)
    {
        await _dataSource.UpdateDataSourceAsync(id, input);
    }
}
```

The database table:

[image: this is database]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have another `DbContext` that inherits from `AbpZeroCommonDbContext` or `AbpZeroDbContext`, then you should inherit one of those.

If you do, then copy `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` from `AbpZeroCommonDbContext` to your `DbContext`. (Since you have `AbpEntityChanges` table in your database, it means you do.)

```cs
public class ReportDesignDbContext : AbpDbContext
{
    // IDbSets
    // ...

    public IEntityHistoryHelper EntityHistoryHelper { get; set; }

    // Constructors
    // ...

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var changeSet = EntityHistoryHelper?.CreateEntityChangeSet(ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList());
        var result = base.SaveChanges();

        EntityHistoryHelper?.Save(changeSet);

        return result;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var changeSet = EntityHistoryHelper?.CreateEntityChangeSet(ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList());
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (EntityHistoryHelper != null)
        {
            await EntityHistoryHelper.SaveAsync(changeSet);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

References:

- [Entity History is not working if project uses multiple dbcontext #6371](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/6371)
- [Entity History is not working for the new custom Modules #3892](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3892)
- `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` from `AbpZeroCommonDbContext`

  - ASP.NET Core: [AbpZeroCommonDbContext.cs#L192-L215](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/99bb6c99faa264b689385b95caf412443b1bfcd5/src/Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore/Zero/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpZeroCommonDbContext.cs#L192-L215)
  - ASP.NET MVC 5: [AbpZeroCommonDbContext.cs#L227-L250](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/99bb6c99faa264b689385b95caf412443b1bfcd5/src/Abp.Zero.EntityFramework/Zero/EntityFramework/AbpZeroCommonDbContext.cs#L227-L250)

Comment: If i use the IEntityHistoryHelper,I must install Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore package,but I can't use EntityFrameworkCore, my development environment is .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: IEntityHistoryHelper is also implemented in Abp.Zero.EntityFramework package, which your project should already depend on.

Comment: I added your code to my project, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please share a repro project that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template).

Comment: Is it a logged in user?

Comment: No login, later I will get user information from JWT Token and write Changes, now I want to record Changes to the database first

Comment: I pushed my project to GitHub and this is an SSH connection:git@github.com:shishuai0410/TempProject.git,if you have time to help me check what is the problem,thanks

Comment: Please fork from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template) so I can see your changes as diff in commits.

Comment: You didn't even add the answer in your [ReportDesignDbContext.cs](https://github.com/shishuai0410/TempProject/blob/main/PDE.ReportDesign.EntityFramework/EntityFramework/ReportDesignDbContext.cs).

Comment: `EntityChangeEventHelper` and `EntityHistoryHelper` are distinct separate concepts.

Comment: I created template from https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates, didn't include login, register, user, role and tenant management pages.     Just a base template, and i deleted test and webapi, i think i forked from module-zero-templat,, i don't understand your "Please fork from aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template so I can see your changes as diff in commits",so i'm wrong? i'm a rookie. Lol,God i'm so stupid.

Comment: Read [docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo).

Comment: Fork from [aspnetboilerplate-templates](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-templates) instead of [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template) to not include login, register, user, role and tenant management pages.

Comment: I re-created the project according to what you said.The target version was v2.x and the target framework was Full.NET Framework. Does it support running on .NET Framework 4.6? If my server does not have a cross-platform(.NET Core) environment installed.

Comment: That should be the same as the downloaded template; you have to try it to know.